# Свадьбы: золотая, серебряная, ситцевая и т.д.

Tags: этимология

Каждая круглая дата совместной жизни супругов как-то называется: ситцевая свадьба, соломенная, серебряная, золотая... всех не помню. Интересно, а откуда такие названия?

Answer (score 3):

Зелёная свадьба — день бракосочетания. Её символ — миртовые листья в свадебном венце.
Ситцевая свадьба — один год совместной жизни. В символике названия ситцевой годовщины свадьбы заключена некоторая двусмысленность. Консервативные источники утверждают, что в течение первого года со дня свадьбы отношения похожи на самую непрочную ткань — ситец. А молодые за 1 год свадьбы только-только узнали друг друга ближе; их отношения ещё весьма непрочны, потому и являются «ситцевыми». Однако, задорная народная молва приписывает названию «ситцевая свадьба» несколько иное значение, куда проще разъясняя смысл ситцевой и марлевой годовщин. В народе вполне резонно полагали, что первый год совместной жизни примечателен чрезвычайно активными действиями новобрачных в постели, что, собственно, и ведёт к износу ситцевого постельного белья до состояния марли. Молодожёны дарят в этот день друг другу ситцевые платочки. Иногда она называется хлопчатобумажной. Называется она так потому, что жизнь молодоженов уже вошла в будни. Также в этот день выпивают одну бутылку шампанского, оставленную специально со свадьбы. На празднование ситцевой свадьбы обязательно приглашаются свидетели и лучшие друзья, а также родители.
Бумажная свадьба — двухлетняя годовщина. Обычно дарят альбомы, записные книжки, книги по искусству.
Кожаная свадьба — 3 года совместной жизни.
Льняная свадьба — отмечается через четыре года. Лён является символом достатка и роскоши, которую могли себе позволить немногие. Принято дарить изделия из льна: полотенца, скатерти, простыни, покрывала и т. д. Обязательным украшением на столах являются красивые свечи. Лен — символ прочности и долговечности, он гораздо прочнее ситца, а значит, и отношения супругов стали более крепкими и надежными. До наших дней дошёл обряд — осыпание супругов на четвертую годовщину свадьбы льняными семенами. Родственники, друзья и все приглашенные обсыпают юбиляров в этот день конфетами и семенами льна.
Деревянная свадьба — отмечается пятилетие семейной жизни. В этот день обычно дарят различные деревянные вещи.
Чугунная свадьба — 6-летие совместной жизни.
Цинковая свадьба — отмечается через шесть с половиной лет, напоминает о том, что на брак, как на оцинкованную посуду, нужно время от времени наводить глянец.
Медная свадьба — празднуется через семь лет. Супруги обмениваются медными монетами в залог будущего счастья.
Жестяная свадьба — 8 лет. В этот день дарят блестящие домашние предметы, например, формы для кексов. Реже встречается название этой годовщины, как кроватная свадьба. На годовщину принято покупать новую кровать, как символ обновления домашнего очага.
Фаянсовая свадьба — 9 лет супружества. На годовщину дарятся фаянсовая посуда, изделия из хрусталя.
День роз (оловянная свадьба) — десятилетний юбилей свадьбы. В этот день приглашаются в гости лица, бывшие на свадьбе шаферами и подружками. Танцуют с красными розами.
Стальная свадьба — 11 лет совместной жизни. Принято дарить сувениры из стали, а также различные электроинструменты.
Никелевая свадьба — 12,5 лет брачной жизни.
Ландышевая (кружевная) свадьба — 13 лет
Агатовая свадьба — 14 лет брачной жизни. На эту годовщину дарят изделия из слоновой кости или агата.
Стеклянная свадьба (хрустальная свадьба) — через 15 лет, когда дарят стеклянные предметы в знак того, что отношения между супругами должны быть чистыми, как стёклышко.
Бирюзовая свадьба — 18 годовщина свадьбы. Древние персы считали бирюзу камнем счастья, а арабы — камнем, приносящим победу. Много сот лет назад хорошая бирюза ценилась выше золота. Вы вместе 18 лет, это значит, что вы тоже одержали победу над временем, трудностями и невзгодами и сохранили ваш союз. Отметьте эту дату вдвоем и подарите друг другу украшения из бирюзы или вещи, инкрустированные бирюзой.
Фарфоровая свадьба — 20 лет. Праздничный стол сервируется новым фарфоровым сервизом в знак того, что от старых сервизов не осталось и следа.
Атласная свадьба — 24 года. Когда вместе 24 года, оглядываешься назад осознавая счастье прожитых лет, понимая то, что Ваша вторая половинка должна оставаться неизмененной.
Серебряная свадьба — 25 лет. Собирается вся родня. В этот день рядом с золотым обручальным кольцом надевается серебряное.
Жемчужная свадьба — 30 лет. Она напоминает о том, что 30 лет, прожитых вместе, «нанизываются», как жемчуг в ожерелье.
Коралловая свадьба — 35 лет.
Алюминиевая свадьба — 37,5 лет — говорит о долгом и прочном счастье супружеской пары.
Ртутная свадьба — 38 лет — предоставляет редкую возможность для преобразования в своей жизни всего того, что хотелось бы изменить. Это время благоприятно для самых активных совместных действий, не упустите этот уникальный шанс!
Рубиновая свадьба — 40 лет. В обручальное золотое кольцо вделывают рубин — камень любви и огня.
Сапфировая свадьба — 45 лет со дня бракосочетания.
Золотая свадьба — 50 лет. В этот день очень часто старые обручальные кольца заменяют новыми. Ведь пальцы, носившие эти кольца, изменились, а золото стёрлось.
Изумрудная свадьба — 55 лет.
Бриллиантовая свадьба — 60 лет. Означает, что ничто уже не может расторгнуть этот брак.
Железная свадьба — 65 лет брачной жизни.
Каменная свадьба — 67,5 лет совместной жизни.
Благодатная свадьба — 70 лет совместной жизни.
Коронная свадьба — 75 лет совместной жизни.
Дубовая свадьба — 80 лет совместной жизни.
Гранитная свадьба — 90 лет совместной жизни.
Платиновая (красная) свадьба — 100 лет совместной жизни. Известно, что её праздновали 126-летний Нифтулла Агаев из села Зувуч в Азербайджане со своей 116-летней супругой Балабеим Агаевой.

Answer (score 2):

Названия придуманы, причем сравнительно недавно. Возможно, за исключением серебряной и золотой. Об этом свидетельствует, например, тот факт, что нет единого списка соответствия юбилеев и материалов. Думаю, что это продукт советской эпохи. Что-то я не встречал упоминаний о подобных мероприятиях  до революции. 
Серебряную свадьбу объясняли появлением "серебра" в волосах супругов, про золотую - даже и не скажу, не зубами же золотыми... Со временем все быстро забылось, появились многочисленные "теоретические" обоснования (наподобие представленного), крайне непоследовательные и взаимоисключающие, родом обычно - из "женских" журналов.

Я, собственно, не против, нехай каждый празднуют хоть нанотехнологическую, только не надо выдавать очевидный новодел за артефакт царя Гороха.

Comment: Может, золото - символ прочности? Шутка ли, прожить вместе 50 лет!

Comment: Еще такая мысль. Серебряные и тем более золотые свадьбы становятся редкостью, а попраздновать-то хочется! Скоро каждый месяц праздновать начнут :-))

Comment: Корпус русского языка поддерживает эту точку зрения. Самое раннее упоминание «золотой свадьбы» датируется [1903 г.](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%22%E7%EE%EB%EE%F2%E0%FF+%F1%E2%E0%E4%FC%E1%E0%22), а «серебряной» — [1861-2](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%22%E7%EE%EB%EE%F2%E0%FF%20%F1%E2%E0%E4%FC%E1%E0%22&p=1)

Comment: Других свадеб я там не нашла. (Искала не все). Да и было бы странно прочитать, что лица, настолько важные, чтобы о них писали в книгах или газетах, праздновали бы  ситцевую или чугунную свадьбы.